# reading line by line and sectionning each 15 lines into a mutidimmensional array

Tags: php, oop, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to block out a text into blocks.

```
$file = fopen("output.txt", "r");

while(! feof($file))
{
$line = fgets($file);  

  if (preg_match('/Enterprise Weekly Time Sheets Date:/',$line)){
    echo("<br>Time Sheet Date found ");
       $data = explode(' ', $line);
         echo sprintf("%40s\n", $data[5]); 
  }
  if (preg_match('/UNREGISTERED COPY Selection Dates: /',$line)){
    echo("<br>Selection Dates found ");
       $data = explode(' ', $line);
         echo sprintf("%40s %40s\n", $data[4], $data[5]); 
  }
  if (preg_match('/Id\#/',$line)){
    echo("<br>Id found ");
        $data = explode(' ', $line);
         echo sprintf("%40s %40s\n", $data[7], $data[1]); 
  }
  if (preg_match('/TOTAL HOURS: /',$line)){

          $data = explode(' ', $line);
         echo sprintf("%40s %40s %40s\n", $data[2], $data[4], $data[7]); 
  }

}
```

I'm already parsing the data and have access to the variables while on the WHILE statement.

Right now I keep overriding the data as I go through all the bloc of text.

As per the latest request I have been asked to provide a better image as to what the text file would look like.

View the file [MultipleReport.txt](https://gist.github.com/hayonj/b8e9a6c589553b25ab47) on github.

Ideally I'm parsing all the records line by line, every 15 lines I preg_match and store all the variable and put all the content into a dimensional array.

For each 15 lines of text one employee will have all of it's detail.
Like so :

```
$employees = [
1 => [
    'CreationDate' => "10-13-2014",
    'SelectionDate1' => "09-29-2014",
    'SelectionDate2' => "10-05-2014",
    'Company' => "00010453",
    'Id' => "000007062",
    'Name' => "HAYES GILL",
    'RegHours' => 40.00,
    'OverHours' => 2.50,
    'TotalHours' => 42.50,
],
2 => [
    'CreationDate' => "10-13-2014",
    'SelectionDate1' => "09-29-2014",
    'SelectionDate2' => "10-05-2014",
    'Company' => "00010453",
    'Id' => "000007081",
    'Name' => "JONES TOM",
    'RegHours' => 40.00,
    'OverHours' => 12.50,
    'TotalHours' => 52.50,
]
];
```

Would it be easier to collect the data through a Multidimesional array or maybe create an object with OOP class ?

Comment: where is your codes thats pushing the values inside that container?

Comment: I just edited it.. I didn't think it was needed.

Comment: The `file()` function returns an array with each line as an element in that array.

Comment: Ok well going from there I get every 15 lines a new EMPLOYEE to parse it's data and save it into a multidirectional array but I need to keep going until the end of the file is reached.

Comment: just put a counter above the loop, then use a modulo condition for every 15th row. then process then push as `$data[] = whatever contents`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building the array with an index?

```
$data = array();
$ct = 0;
$ix = 0;
foreach(file("output.txt") as $line){
    $ct++
    $lines[] = $line;
    if($ct==15){
        $line = implode("\r\n",$lines);
        $ct = 0;
        $ix++;
        if (preg_match('/Enterprise Weekly Time Sheets Date:/',$line)){
            echo("<br>Time Sheet Date found ");
            $data[$ix] = explode(' ', $line);
            echo sprintf("%40s\n", $data[5]); 
        }
        if (preg_match('/UNREGISTERED COPY Selection Dates: /',$line)){
            echo("<br>Selection Dates found ");
            $data[$ix] = explode(' ', $line);
            echo sprintf("%40s %40s\n", $data[4], $data[5]); 
        }
        if (preg_match('/Id\#/',$line)){
            echo("<br>Id found ");
            $data[$ix] = explode(' ', $line);
            echo sprintf("%40s %40s\n", $data[7], $data[1]); 
        }
        if (preg_match('/TOTAL HOURS: /',$line)){
            $data[$ix] = explode(' ', $line);
            echo sprintf("%40s %40s %40s\n", $data[2], $data[4], $data[7]); 
        }
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: as $ix $line (is this a typo )  ? - Should I put this instead of the while statement completely

Comment: I really need to block each 15 lines and parse through them after they have been added to the array

Comment: I adjusted the answer to create 15 line blocks

Comment: this is good ! but I think every 15 lines it reparses the file completly so I end up with     1 - 12 - 123

Comment: May I suggest posting the file you're attempting to parse here and the expected output of the script.